# Retrieve specific values from "child" table (JPQL)

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I have what I am sure is a simple problem, but am having problems trying to make it work. In a nutshell, I have a search feature in a web app (using JPA 2.1, Java 1.7.0 JDK, Primefaces 4.0, Oracle 10g db, JBoss EAP 6.2, NetBeans 8.0 IDE) that is supposed to search 2 tables in a database ("parent" and "child"). More specifically I want to grab 2 values from the child table, and, along with data from the parent table, populate a form with the results.

Entities:

"Parent" entity

```
`@Entity
@Table(name = "FOREIGN_PARTY")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "ForeignParty.findbyPolicy1Num", query = "SELECT f FROM ForeignParty f JOIN f.policyPaymentCollection pp WHERE pp.policy1Num = :policy1Num")})

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "foreignPartyId")
    private Collection<PolicyPayment> policyPaymentCollection;

// getter and setter for Collection field`
```

"Child" entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POLICY_PAYMENT")

@JoinColumn(name = "FOREIGN_PARTY_ID", referencedColumnName = "FOREIGN_PARTY_ID")
@ManyToOne
private ForeignParty foreignPartyId;

// getter and setter for foreignPartyId field
```

Based on criteria User enters on a primefaces search form, the following logic is invoked:

```
public void findSearchCriteriaItems() {
    if (!selected.getSourceClientId().equals("") && !selected.getSourceSystem().equals("")
            && !this.policyPaymentController.getSelected().getPolicy1Num().equals("")) {
        listSearchItemsEJB = ejbFacade.findRecordsBySourceSystemClientIdPolicyNum(selected.getSourceClientId(), 
            selected.getSourceSystem(), this.policyPaymentController.getSelected().getPolicy1Num());
    } else if (!selected.getSourceClientId().equals("") && this.policyPaymentController.getSelected().getPolicy1Num().equals("")
            && selected.getSourceSystem().equals("")) {
        listSearchItemsEJB = ejbFacade.findRecordsBySourceClientId(selected.getSourceClientId());
    } else if (selected.getSourceClientId().equals("")  && this.policyPaymentController.getSelected().getPolicy1Num().equals("")
            && !selected.getSourceSystem().equals("")) {
        listSearchItemsEJB = ejbFacade.findRecordsBySourceSystem(selected.getSourceSystem());
    } else if (selected.getSourceSystem().equals("") && selected.getSourceClientId().equals("") 
            && !this.policyPaymentController.getSelected().getPolicy1Num().equals("")) {
        listSearchItemsEJB = ejbFacade.findRecordsByPolicyNum(this.policyPaymentController.getSelected().getPolicy1Num());
    } else {
        listSearchItemsEJB = null;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listSearchItemsEJB.size(); i++) {
        ForeignParty searchRecords = listSearchItemsEJB.get(i);
        items.add((ForeignParty) searchRecords);
    }
}
```

Facade the queries the db:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "FatcaPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    private Query query;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

public List<ForeignParty> findRecordsByPolicyNum(String policyNum) {
        query = em.createNamedQuery("ForeignParty.findbyPolicy1Num");
        query.setParameter("policy1Num", policyNum);
        List<ForeignParty> searchCriteriaList  = (List<ForeignParty>) query.getResultList();
        return searchCriteriaList;
    }
```

The problem is that not all data is being returned from the "child" table, and therefore not being populated in the form. So, basically, there are only 2 values from the "child" table that I need to retrieve and drop into the form. My apologies if the above code seems confusing. I left a lot out because these classes are fairly large. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if any more info is needed I will gladly provide it. Thanks!

Comment: "*The problem is that not all data is being returned from the "child" table, and therefore not being populated in the form.*" Why does not? If you want to combine a result list from more than one table in the underlying database, you just need a join query retrieving a selected number of columns (or all) from those associated tables.

Comment: Hi Tiny, I did try editing the query in the Parent entity to: 'SELECT pp.policy1Num, pp.totalPayoutAmt FROM ForeignParty f JOIN f.policyPaymentCollection pp WHERE pp.policy1Num = :policy1Num"' but I get an error indicating that the policy1Num and totalPayoutAmt String values cannot be cast to type ForeignParty. I think that relates to the iteration logic here: 'for (int i = 0; i < listSearchItemsEJB.size(); i++) {
        ForeignParty searchRecords = listSearchItemsEJB.get(i);
        items.add((ForeignParty) searchRecords);
    }'

Comment: Just return a result list based on filter condition(s) (specify them in the `WHERE` clause) and sort order(s) (specify them in the `ORDER BY` clause) if any. That `for` is completely unnecessary. (It is just like basic JDBC).

Comment: Would I not need to have the 'for' statement in order to add the records returned in the resultlist, in order to then populate the form? Or would that data be returned in a readable format based on filter conditions in a 'WHERE' clause? Could you also give me an idea of how the 'WHERE' clause should look?

Comment: Are you using a (stateless) EJB in this case? There are some design mistakes. Disregarding the Facade, a query instance should not be an instance variable (`private Query query;`). It should be a method local variable. The list holding data returned as a query result (i.e. `listSearchItemsEJB`) should also be used locally. This is a dynamic query. Thus, the JPA criteria API is the way to go but it has a learning curve (if you have not yet used it).

Comment: Yes, I am using a stateless EJB. I agree on the design mistakes, and I am sure by looking at what code I have provided, you can tell I am newbie to the entire JPA/JTA process. I definitely don't want to you have to submit lines of code to show me how to do it, but can you elaborate a little on your explanation with one- or two-liner code samples? For example, you say that listSearchItemsEJB should be used locally. Could you include a bit of code to give me an idea of how it should look?